# Maple and substrings

Tags: math, encoding, maple

Maybe this is the wrong website to ask, but hopefully somebody knows...

How do I break a string in Maple and store it in a list of substrings?

i.e.
my string is : "i love the weekends"

and I want to break it into substrings of size 2...
so i would look like this

substrs;

substrs = [[i ][lo][ve][ t][he][ w][ee][ke][nd][s ]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LengthSplit` in the `StringTools` package seems to do what you want:

```
substrs := StringTools[LengthSplit]("i love the weekends", 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

> this works great! How would you convert it to a list though? – user69514 Apr 20 '09 at 17:36

Simple, just put a list constructor around it:

```
substrs := [StringTools[LengthSplit]("i love the weekends", 2)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s := "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
s[1..2];
seq(s[i..i+1], i=1..length(s), 2);
```

Comment: This approach does not scale well for long strings. At length=10^6 it is about 350 time slower then LengthSplit on 64bit Windows Maple 17 on a fast Intel i7. The effect worsens as the length grows. For length=2*10^6 it is about 850 times slower.